# WCF - push data from web app to windows form application

Tags: wcf

I am not sure though what exactly to ask since im very new to `WCF`. So I'll try to explain what I am doing. I need to create a web app with textbox and button. On button_click the data in the textbox should be push on a win form app supposedly to be deployed to a client. So what's connecting them is the `wcf` service. I am not exactly looking for codes as solution rather a theory or what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this question would do. how can i pass data from wcf service to windows form. is that possible? i mean no mouse events, no clicking anywhere from the windows forms. please help :/

Comment: It is doable, but it depends on how the client (I'll assume that the server is iis 7.5). Is the client on the same box, one another machine on the intranet, or on the internet?

Comment: no sir. the client is on different location and could be multiple clients waiting for the data from the web app.

Answer (score 0):

The simple method is to have your web site publish the button state and have the clients poll for updates. That is very easy to do with wcf, all you have to think about is security - if any.

The hard way is to let the clients to "sign" up on the wep application and then push the state to the clients. Each client would need its own wcf listening endpoint that can be called from the web application. The implementation is simple enough, but I'll suspect that you will run into issues with connectivity. Do the end user have rights to open ports for listening in windows? If the clients are behind nat-routers can you be sure that you can connect to them?

Comment: Well as of now I've made the clients poll for the data updates from the web site. But I'm looking for other approach that wouldn't require polling of data from the clients. Opening a port should be done by the administrator and i think i won't have problem with it. I found some samples as my references that really helps me a lot with this problem however those are using the netHttpbinding. I'm looking for netTcpbinding. anyways, thanks for the responses.